# Jena package does not exist

Tags: jena, mesa

Hi all I have a java program inside it I have imported these classes.

1. import com.hp.hpl.mesa.rdf.jena.mem.ModelMem;
2. import com.hp.hpl.mesa.rdf.jena.model.*;
3. import com.hp.hpl.mesa.rdf.jena.common.PropertyImpl;

when I'm trying to compile the program it shows 3 errors which are:

1. package com.hp.hpl.mesa.rdf.jena.mem does not exist import
   com.hp.hpl.mesa.rdf.jena.mem.ModelMem;
2. package com.hp.hpl.mesa.rdf.jena.model does not exist import
   com.hp.hpl.mesa.rdf.jena.model.*;
3. package com.hp.hpl.mesa.rdf.jena.common does not exist import
   com.hp.hpl.mesa.rdf.jena.common.PropertyImpl;

I have tried to search for the jar files but I couldn't, is anyone has the link to download the jar file of those packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Jena packages are under `com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf…`. I don't know where you got this `com.hp.hpl.mesa.rdf.jena…` package name from, but it's definitely wrong. Maybe you're using an obsolete example from an ancient Jena version?

There shouldn't be any reason to import `ModelMem` or `PropertyImpl` directly. If you need a `ModelMem`, use `ModelFactory.createDefaultModel()`. If you need a property instance, use `model.createProperty()`.

You can download the Jena jars from the [Jena download site](http://incubator.apache.org/jena/download/index.html).

Comment: Thank you very much your answer was helpful.

Comment: Not to be selfish, but then the least you could do is upvote and accept the answer…

Comment: Jena was originally born in an experimental project called Mesa way back in the mists of time at HPLabs. Jena2 then became an artifact in its own right, with the current package structure. Whatever documentation JavaCrawler is looking at, it's beyond out-of-date. I'm kinda curious to know, actually!